# Nodejs + Mongoose + Prisma Memory Leak

Tags: node.js, mongoose, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools, prisma

I am trying to debug my nodejs application for possible memory leaks, using chrome debug tool. I took 2 heap snapshots - before(snapshot-A) and after(snapshot-B) leaky operation.

I have defined a function which fetches docs from mongoDB collection, for which I am using mongoose framework. I suspect this function to cause memory leak.

```
const res = await dbModel.find(<query>).lean().exec()
```

In snapshot-B, under summary view I found strings related to mongoDB docs fields/values. These strings were stored in map referenced by some prisma related constructor.

After taking multiple snapshots, there was no change and could find same database docs field/values related strings under summary>(string) view in chrome heap profile debug tool.

From this, I implied memory leak. **But I am not sure if its because of prisma or mongoose and how to avoid such memory leaks** ?

[image]

Thanks!